# Text with "f" following "i", cannot see the dot on the "i", sans font

Tags: android, button, fonts, textview

I have a Button in which there is the text "Send files", but I cant see the dot on the top of the "i". I am using the default font (which is "sans", as far as I understand, but correct me if I am wrong).

Here is the `xml` for my `Button` :

```
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_send_files"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                android:padding="20dip"
                android:text="Send files"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
```

If someone has some sort of trick to display the dot on the "i", it would be grea, because it's ugly as it is for now...

I am using a Nexus 7, if it can help.

[image]

Comment: use a magnifier, there is the dot!

Comment: @matheszabi you asked for trouble and here it is ... :P

Comment: Oh, a magnifier... In my opinion, the "i" isn't visible, or it isn't centered, if you look closely (with a magnifier if you want :D)

Comment: You could always just use a different font.

Comment: Yes, but I don't like this idea so much... First, I would have to change it in the whole application, and second, the other basic fonts aren't realy good looking in my opinion. This is why I am trying to find another solution

Comment: "the other basic fonts aren't realy good looking in my opinion" that is only your problem :) Change the font and problem is solved or change the "Sans" font everywhere in World, if you have enough power and don't have any other problems :))

Comment: So my problem is just that the basic Android font was made with mistakes? Cripes!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are seeing is a [ligature](http://ilovetypography.com/2007/09/09/decline-and-fall-of-the-ligature/) glyph for the combination of 'f' + 'i' characters. Frequently, the combination of the standalone 'f' + standalone 'i' will end up in conflict: the overhanging portion of the 'f' will collide with the dot of the 'i'.

The use of a ligature glyph to represent the combination of characters allows a font designer to avoid a collision. In this case, the font designer opted to omit the dot of the 'i'. In other font designs, the dot of the 'i' will stay but the length of the overhanging portion of the 'f' will change so as to avoid a collision. If you examine some other font designs that include a ligature for 'f' + 'i' you will see these different visual treatments. As this is a font design decision, it's difficult to characterize this as a "mistake"; more like "bad design" (I agree with you that it does not look very good).

Comment: Thanks for your precise answer. I had no idea that this could be this kind of explanation. Just one last question, if I may : do you know any way to avoid using this "ligature" and use normal f and i characters?

Comment: In some text layout schemes, it is possible for the programmer to override the default settings and disable things like ligatures and other font-based features. I don't know enough about Android to say whether that is the case; sorry about that. A search for something like "disable ligatures android textview" might get you going down the right path.

Comment: I looked for it but did'nt find any solution... The best I can do is writing Send Files instead of Send files, which is totally acceptable

Comment: Right, that will work fine for text that is under your control, as is the case when creating a Button. But you may still face the issue if you utilize text that you don't control. For example: creating a widget based on user (or other) supplied text. That may not be an issue for you right now, but it's something to be aware of. Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

To disable ligatures, you can use the [android:fontFeatureSettings](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:fontFeatureSettings) attribute on your `TextView`. This attribute accepts valid values for the CSS property `font-feature-settings`. Here's a [list of examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-feature-settings#Examples) from the MDN. They give an example of disabling ligatures there.

Here's how you'd use it on an `TextView` (I've verified this works):

```
android:fontFeatureSettings="liga 0"
```

You can also do this in styles.xml:

```
<style name="your_text_style">
    <item name="android:fontFeatureSettings">liga 0</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

Starting with Lollipop, you can now use [`android:fontFeatureSettings`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:fontFeatureSettings) or [`setFontFeatureSettings()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setFontFeatureSettings(java.lang.String)) to [disable ligatures](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-fonts/#propdef-font-feature-settings).

Answer (score 1):

Changing the font is the only viable solution at the moment. Ligature glyphs aren't handled well for `Roboto-Regular`. Try changing the font to `sans`. Its not elegant, but it works.

Comment: I think I am already using sans font, as I explained in the question

Comment: I think the default font for nexus 7 is Roboto Regular. All OS versions after ICS use Roboto as default font.

Comment: Therefore Roboto Regular equals sans since ICS

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old but it's the top result when you google "disable ligatures on android". Apparently there's a way to do it, but it only works API 21 and newer. So here's my solution. Download the free font editing program FontForge, remove the ligature glyphs from the actual font (fi and fl), and resave the font file. Works like a charm!