# "Dot" present in "i" is not showing in TextView

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView,In that i need to show "Stay away from the fire.".In this sentence "**dot**" is not shown above "i". Screenshot is added for reference.

[image]

**This behavior is not in all the android devices**

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: This may be bcz of the default font implemented by watch. Have you tried using custom font?

Comment: The character combination "fi" is often replaced by a ligature where the dot on the i melts together with the f. This is a feature, not a bug.

Comment: @Henry,Can u send me any reference link?

Comment: @kavie https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature

Comment: @Henry,Thanks  a lot

Comment: that is caused by device default font. You can use your own font to prevent this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this issue by adding android:fontFeatureSettings="liga 0" to TextView

Reference Link : [Text with "f" following "i", cannot see the dot on the "i", sans font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17655153/text-with-f-following-i-cannot-see-the-dot-on-the-i-sans-font)

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works for me

**Add xml:**

```
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/textview"
android:maxLines="1" // or any number of lines you want
android:ellipsize="end" />
```