# TextView display string containing "fi" issue

Tags: android, textview

I have been struggling to fix an issue of display a string which contains a pattern of "fi" such as word "munificent" in Android TextView. That was displayed wrong by missing the dot of the letter "i". I have tried to set font, android:textScaleX, and even tried using WebView. They are all same result. Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably seeing the "fi" ligature. It is a source of many complaints. There is even an online [petition](https://www.change.org/p/google-disable-the-fi-ligature-on-android) to get rid of it.

Evidently, you can get rid of it by setting the `android:fontFeatureSettings` attribute on a `TextView` for Lollipop and up. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17655153/text-with-f-following-i-cannot-see-the-dot-on-the-i-sans-font) question for some guidance.